# Gather (or stack) values from columns ignoring NA's in R

Tags: r, plyr

Let's say i have this df:

```
>df
ID  V1 V2 V3 
1   24 81 NA 
2   22 34 32 
3   88 NA NA
```

And i'd like to gather them like this (removing the NA's)

```
>df
ID VAR VAL
1  V1  24
1  V2  81
2  V1  22
2  V2  34
2  V3  32
3  V1  88
```

I've tried using `gather` from `plyr` but don't know how to keep the column `id`. I've read their documentation with ?gather but still couldn't figure it out. Here's the simple code i'm using:

`gather(df, key = id)`

Comment: `tidyr::gather(df, var, val, -ID, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! That was exactly what i was looking for.